# Port Web Scraper/ Web Crawler over to a Mobile Device?

Tags: mobile, web-crawler, porting, smartphone

Is it possible to port a web scraper/web crawler over to a mobile device such as a smart phone? If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is a loaded question... of course it is possible, but why would you want to?

> If so, how would I do it?

Well, you would take an existing web crawler and port it. As a matter of fact, you might not have to do much porting: if you take a crawler like [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/about.html), it's already written in Java, it's available to download as a package so you can just drop it in your android phone, get root access and run the crawler. **But again: why would you want to do it?**

Whatever your goal is, I would think that putting a web crawler on a smart phone would be an overkill. So what's your goal?